# How to get the result values appended to an CSV file in jmeter(groovy)

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am getting a value from HTTP request which I am writing it into a CSV file, each and every time when the program is executed, the new values are overwritten and not appended to the CSV. I would like to append the values instead of overwriting. I am using Regex and XPath extractor to get the values from the HTTP requests and writing it an CSV file.

```
new File('/Users/ddd/testgui/queueId1.csv').newWriter().withWriter { w -> 
   w << vars.get('queueid')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works for me, on groovysh 2.5.3 :

```
new File('/Users/ddd/testgui/queueId1.csv').newWriter(true).withWriter { w -> 
  w << vars.get('queueid') 
}
```

The true in the newWriter is for append == true.

Comment: first answer was incorrect. the correction above was done on a blank-slate docker, and writing a random string instead of vars.get('queueid').

Comment: It gets appended in the same line, I want it in the next line. I tried this code with .txt  file

Comment: Aha the element, you are capturing needs a newline. Change:

    << vars.get('queueid')

to
   << vars.get('queueid') << '\n'

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do just:

```
new File('/Users/ddd/testgui/queueId1.csv') << vars.get('queueid')
```

---

Be aware that your code is going to work fine **only when you have 1 thread**, if there will be more - you may suffer from a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2 threads will be simultaneously writing into a file.

If you're going to execute this code with > 1 virtual user I would rather recommend going for [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) functionality.

If you add the next line to **user.properties** file:

```
sample_variables=queueid
```

and restart JMeter to pick the property up next time you run your test the .jtl results file will have an extra column with `queueid` variable value for each thread/request.

If you want to store it into a separate file - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dmitri T. I tried this, there were some issues with flexible file writer, the values from the regex were displayed thrice in the flexible file writer (NOTE: I have script to get the unique value from the regex as the regex gives values like _g, _g0, _g1 )